# Cannot Edit ArcGIS Server Map service with feature access enabled

Tags: arcgis-server, editing, web-service

My problem is that I can't edit the features in my ArcGIS server map service but when I publish this service to ArcGIS online all editing functions work very well, So here is what i have done:

- ArcGIS Server account has higher-level permissions
- The connection to the database is in a folder where ArcGIS Server account has full access permissions
- The database is registered with ArcGIS server
- The map service is published with feature access enabled

Once I had this issue and I turned around using web-adaptor URL but now I can't so I need some help.